# AngularJS forEach and adding values

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
var grandTotal;
angular.forEach($scope.gear, function(value, key) {
    var rowTotal = value.amount * value.price;
    console.log(rowTotal);
    grandTotal += rowTotal; 
});
console.log('grandTotal: '+grandTotal);
```

I have the above that I'm trying to get a grant total for, It seems to return NaN for my `grandTotal`

UPDATE:

```
var grandTotal = 0;
angular.forEach($scope.gear, function(value, key) {
    var rowTotal = value.amount * value.price;
    rowTotal = rowTotal.toFixed(1);
    console.log(rowTotal);
    grandTotal += rowTotal;
});
console.log('grandTotal: '+parseFloat(grandTotal));
```

this returns [image]

Comment: can you please post sample data for $scope.gear object

Comment: I guess your grandTotal variable was not initialized :) So grandTotal += rowTotal will result in nan.
Use
var grandTotal = 0;

Comment: @guru I have updated the Original Post with the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using vanilla javascript `map` and `reduce` functions ?

An exemple based on your purpose here : http://jsfiddle.net/optyler/G2ZJa/